# Tangential acceleration and the transverse acceleration?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, acceleration, vectors

i'm studying Classical mechanics from **Analytical mechanics textbook** , and i'm encounter with transverse acceleration in Chapter five **The term $\omega \times r'$ is called the transverse acceleration, because it is perpendicular to the position vector r'. It appears as a result of any angular acceleration of the rotating system, that is, if the angular velocity vector is changing in either magnitude or direction, or both.** as stated previously , the textbook has not mentioned the tangential acceleration , so is there any difference between the tangential and the transverse acceleration? or he was talking about the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a car driving in a circle. Transverse acceleration is centripetal acceleration. It is transverse or perpendicular to the direction of travel.

Tangential acceleration would be if the driver stepped on the brakes or gas. It is along the direction of motion, or tangent to the trajectory.

Comment: According to their statement, transverse acceleration is perpendicular to the position vector and not the direction of travel, so it cant be the centripetal acceleration right ?

Answer (score 0):

The term reads $\omega \times r'$, probably meaning $r'= dr/dt$, so its perpendicular to the tangent to the trajectory and the axis of rotation $\omega$.

With

$$x = r (\cos \phi, \sin \phi )$$

we have the radial acceleration by projection onto the radial unit vector

$$ \ddot x(t) \cdot (\cos (\phi (t)),\sin (\phi (t))) = \ddot r(t) - r(t)\  \dot\phi(t)^2 $$

and the angular acceleration by projection onto the unit tangent vector to the circle at $r$.

$$\ddot x(t) \cdot (-\sin (\phi (t)),\ \cos (\phi (t)))  = 2 \ \dot r(t) \ \dot \phi(t) + r(t) \  \ddot \phi(t)$$

The first term is called Coriolis acceleration, the second is the angular acceleration, both perpendicular to $\vec r$.

So the ominous  book has to have an angular acceleration term $r\times \dot \omega$ in units $\frac{m}{s^2}$

Comment: The OP specifically says that $\mathbf{r}'$ is a position vector, though.

Answer (score 0):

The term $\omega$ x r gives the tangential velocity of the object, where $\omega$ is the angular velocity and r is the position vector. The tangential velocity is the speed with which it undergoes circular motion.

Angular velocity, also known as angular frequency vector, is a representation of how the angular position or orientation of an object changes with time, i.e. how quickly an object rotates around an axis of rotation.

Tangential acceleration is given by $\alpha$ x r and it is the rate at which the tangential velocity varies in the rotational motion of the object. It acts in the direction of a tangent at the point of motion for an object. $\alpha $ is the angular acceleration.

Angular acceleration, also called rotational acceleration, is a quantitative expression of the change in angular velocity that a spinning object undergoes per unit time.

"Tangential and normal" are relative to the direction of travel. "Transverse and radial" are usually relative to the origin of the coordinate system, or the centre of some circular symmetry.

The tangential and normal components can be used for any smooth line or surface, while the transverse and radial components are used when the line is specifically a circle and the surface is specifically a sphere.

In circular motion they mean the same.